# Warnings while compiling a C library

Tags: c, xcode, clang

I am trying to compile a C library and I am getting a loy of warning while doing it. Though the compiled library is working properly, I am still a bit apprehensive about the warnings. I googled all the warnings, but the relevant search results are hard to come by.

The warnings are:

`main(){printf("osx%d", (int) (sizeof(void *)*8));}
^~~~
1 warning generated.
clang: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-s'`

This warning is in the shell script that I used to compile the libraries. Could someone tell me what the -'s' flag is and how I can remove this warning?

Next warning:

`warning: unknown warning option '-Wno-long-double'; did you mean '-Wno-long-long'? [-Wunknown-warning-option]`

and the next one,
`/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/libtool: file: fortify.o has no symbols
clang: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-s'`

Anyway to silence these warning?

Comment: What command do you use to compile? Don't use the options `-s` `-Wno-long-double` .

Comment: Oh, I just noticed the `xcode` flag! Look for `Build Settings` , somewhere after clicking the name of the project on the left side of the UI as I recall. Something like this: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/recipes/xcode_help-project_editor/Articles/Adding%20a%20Compiler%20Flag%20to%20a%20File.html  There are lot of forms, one of them lets you change the command line arguments given to the compiler.

Comment: @BuellaGábor I used a shell command `sh ccc.osx`. The source comes with a `ccc.osx` file. I compiled this using command line.

Comment: @BuellaGábor Are these warnings critical?

Comment: I don't know what `ccc.osx` contains, or what the code is you are building, etc... So I can't tell. Anyways, my best guess is, these are not critical. Mainly just meta warnings, these are warnings about warning settings, not about the actual code. So the actual code can be just fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the manual of gcc for details of what each option should do.

AFAICT, clang not accepting those flags does not lead to any failure of the built executable.

Excerpt:

- -s: Remove all symbol table and relocation information from the executable. (linker)
- -Wno-long-double: Looks like someone wants to disable use of `long double`. Cannot find it for newest GCC. Chances are the code does not contain such anyway.